# Como ler o tamanho de um arquivo mat?

Tags: matlab

Tenho um arquivo mat com determinados dados. Ele tem 10 linhas por 500 colunas mas quando eu faço:

```
matriz = load('Planilha.mat');
disp(size(matriz));
```

O resultado é 1 por 20. O que é totalmente diferente do esperado.

Como eu faço para conseguir o tamanho correto de um arquivo `.mat` ?

Comment: Qual é o formato do arquivo? Descreva um exemplo, na pergunta.

Comment: @Marcelo Uchimura, o formato do arquivo é '.mat', arquivo com dados numéricos.

Comment: Tem certeza que salvou a matriz certa dentro do arquivo?

Comment: Sim, através do workspace do Matlab da para visualizar a matriz.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Além do que [Marcelo Uchimura](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/308567/88991) colocou na resposta, Vale lembrar que quando você usa

```
matrix=load('data.mat')
```

ou

```
matrix=load('data.mat','variavel')
```

Você tem como resposta uma estrutura, não a matrix salva. Supondo que a matrix de chama `mt`, pra acessar ela é necessário usar

```
st=load('data.mat')
matrix=st.mt
```

ou então apenas use

```
load('data.mat')
```

ou

```
load('data.mat','variavel')
```

Isso irá colocar a matriz no workspace, da maneira que você quer.

Answer (score 0):

Inspecione as variáveis salvas dentro do .mat com

```
whos -file Planilha.mat
```

Depois, para carregar a variável que você precisa, faça

```
matriz = load('Planilha.mat','nomedavariavel')
```

Fonte: [aqui](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/load.html)

Comment: Na verdade isso gera uma estrutura.